# Find out my number neighbors

Tags: code-golf, number, array

The input consists of *i* rows with neighbors information. Each *i*<sup>th</sup> row contains 4 values, representing the neighbor of *i* to the **North**, **East**, **South** and **West** directions, respectively. So each value represents a neighbor at the given direction of the *i*<sup>th</sup> row, starting from row 1, and can go up to 65,535 rows. The *0* value indicates no neighbor to that direction.

For instance, if the first row is "0 2 3 10" it means that the *i* neighbor has three other neighbors: no one to the north, neighbor *2* to the east, neighbor *3* to the south and neighbor *10* to the west.

You need to output the array of neighbors, starting from the value which is most to the northwest. Each neighbor will be displayed only once, at its position relative to others. Let's see some examples:

Input:

```
0 0 0 0
```

No neighbors (empty case), output:

```
1
```

Input:

```
0 2 0 0 
0 0 0 1
```

1 has neighbor 2 to the east. 2 has neighbor 1 to the west

Output:

```
1 2
```

Input:

```
0 2 0 0
0 0 3 1
2 0 0 0
```

1 has neighbor 2 to the east. 2 has neighbor 1 to the west and 3 to the south. 
3 has neighbor 2 to the north

Output:

```
1 2
  3
```

Input:

```
2 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
```

Output:

```
2
1
```

Input:

```
0 2 3 0
0 0 4 1
1 4 0 0
2 0 0 3
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
```

**Rules:**

- <strike>Test cases are separated by one **empty line**. Output of different test cases must also be separated by one empty line.</strike>
- The output graph is **always** connected. You are not going to have 1 neighbor to 2 only, along with 3 neighbor to 4 only (isolated from 1-2 component).
- **All entries are valid.** Example of invalid entries:

  - Entries containing letters or any symbol different than spaces, line breaks and digits (0-9).
  - the *i*<sup>th</sup> row containing the *i*<sup>th</sup> value (because one can't be its own neighbor).
  - a negative value or value higher than 65,535.
  - Less than four values in a row.
  - More than four values in a row.
  - The same neighbor pointing to two different directions (ex: 0 1 1 0).

Standard loopholes apply, and the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: How strict are I/O and the order of NESW?  For example, could I take a list of lists in [N, S, W, E] order?

Comment: @Mnemonic Thank you, fixed.

Comment: *Test cases are separated by one empty line* - This is an unusual requirement.  Normally it is given that challenge entries will handle one testcase at a time (one per invocation).  If challenge entries can handle more than one testcase at a time, then great, but there is little value to strictly specifying how multiple testcase entries should be formatted.

Comment: @Digital Trauma Thank you for your edits and also this suggestion. I removed this rule (striked though it).

Comment: @Chaotic you can remove it completely (if you want to), the [revision history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/163295/revisions) take care of the changelog

Comment: @Rod Yes, I'm aware of this, but let it rest some time there, because in the past I was warned against changing the rules in the middle of the challenge. Best regards.

Comment: I don't understand how the output relates to the output. Can you explain in more detail what "array of neighbors" means, and by which rules this array should be created by?

Comment: Aaaaah, I think I get it. The neighbors are enumerated `1,2,...`. I though they had a neighbor 2 "units" to the east, and 1 "unit" to the south and so on. Couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: @StewieGriffin yep I had to read through it a few times before it was clear

Comment: I assume that leading spaces (the same number of spaces per line), trailing spaces, and leading and trailing newlines don't matter in the output. Right? Because there's no way to tell from the input whether such spaces exist.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 152 bytes

```python
l=input()
def f(x,y,n):
 if m[x][y]<n:m[x][y]=n;[f(i%3-1+x,i/3-1+y,h)for h,i in zip(l[n-1],[3,7,5,1])]
e=len(l)
m=eval(`[[0]*e*2]*e*2`)
f(e,e,1)
print m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzRCoIwGIXv9xS7CTY70jaLwPJJxqCgDQfzV8RCe/ml0s35DofDNyxT25PJOTWRhvckJHv5wIOYsYBkzXgMvLOzs4u7U/1vDd1sEPFQlfo4I542Lmhl6EfeIvJI/BsHkSyV2sFWuOIC7aRjvkmeRJKsa/znmcTDWuUKX5g9HpIF4eGhJRvGSBPvcl4fMKigVpOCwhmbU69U@2Y2onLuBw)

The input order is `NESW`
`f` is a recursive function to populate the houses

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. I even tried with your input format (which I guess it's fine): [[0, 5, 2, 0], [1, 6, 3, 0], [2, 7, 4, 0], [3, 8, 0, 0], [0, 9, 6, 1], [5, 10, 7, 2], [6, 11, 8, 3], [7, 12, 0, 4], [0, 13, 10, 5], [9, 14, 11, 6], [10, 15, 12, 7], [11, 16, 0, 8], [0, 17, 14, 9], [13, 18, 15, 10], [14, 19, 16, 11], [15, 20, 0, 12], [0, 21, 18, 13], [17, 22, 19, 14], [18, 23, 20, 15], [19, 24, 0, 16], [0, 0, 22, 17], [21, 0, 23, 18], [22, 0, 24, 19], [23, 0, 0, 20]]

Comment: @Chaotic [seems fine to me](https://tio.run/##NZDNboMwEITvPMVeKpl0o7I2P0lansSykkoFYYk4KEqr0Jen3rV7wZ7ZnU9jlvUx3YLetrn3Yfl@qLL4GkYY1RNXDOWpAD/C1T6dXd1HOOVbH97tqPyL2dPrE/0bnytO5Xi7w4QefIBfv6jZhj05tAY7bJBc6Yqhn4eg5rK49sPP56wu1lZuN@y0fC5lMaoBB6R4iawzk66n5e7DA87bFpcRGgSNUDkESwgtgskquh1CnVV0D/GaVTyPskysIoIq2dYs2SZZNyyjTVqidY6SSYGGdeRQnRKtlOCFJmU6MeKEWgEc/gFdCh1lzrRDDqV3MO@YUiQNeaYrYZDOEE05Jy0ZqXXOSVGeaZNyJFV5putEaTOlyjGpysgqpUi66vRwLYXEMOknMta5Pw) maybe the output format is not satisfactory?

Comment: Ok, I got lost with all those zeros there. I think it woud be better to remove them, but I'm not used to code golf standard rules.

Comment: Do you just remain the unused space?

Answer (score 2):

- still golfing :)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 135 bytes

```javascript
R=>R.map((t,y)=>r.map((T,Y)=>T.map((X,I)=>X==y+1?[-1,1,1,-1].map((x,i)=>t[i]?(r[a=Y+x*-~i%2]=r[a]||[])[I+x*i%2]=t[i]:0):0)),r=[[1]])&&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwDIbvPkUvjtal0s6dhMyzV/GghB6KOqnMVeoQBfHVZ@YkgfD9X/gv/uHvhxRunW7j8dTX2G@w2syv/iZlBy@FVRphC3uG7Qg7WDPsEF@5XZG2MIy2brRPCGw7Cm4lE3nc58@Z/oRp4ZDRvd/kFK05/EXD39IoXgUJiaxzKstSf4jtPTaneRPPspZEBkQBYiHAOJiQ4QuiFGAHsgJKEObvip9jWnCV6r8)

#### _______________________________________________________________

Second approach

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 130 bytes

```javascript
f=(R,x=0,y=0,c=1,r=[[]])=>[-1,1,1,-1].map((d,i)=>(t=R[c-1][i])&&!(r[Y=y+d*-~i%2]=r[Y]||[])[X=x+d*i%2]?f(R,X,Y,t,r):0,r[y][x]=c)&&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5Bi8JADIXv/orxsDKzvspM60nI7n/oSQk5lKmVimtlWpYWZP96NxVJQnjfg5dcq9@qj6l9DNm9q89zQ9q2xEgek06kgETMIo6@OAtYKguy@6ke1tZoFduBSo4KuRW32axt4hNN2/oz@2s/ciGV8nyyOD7SqHiB340eOeKEAckdPBJPwqNQ1IA0x@7ed7fz7tZdbGOZPUwOUxh4wYq9bpi9QVhUMNjD@LeXvzxVhX7s5n8)